# Datagrid rowbackground color

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to change a background color of a row datagrid in codebehing I'm using a binding property
in code behing I see the color changes but when displayed the background color doesn't change.
When  I play with the scroll I some of the

Answer (score 0):

Header Color change:

```
With datagrid1
 .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
 .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
 .EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
End With
```

Row and Background Color Change

```
With datagrid1
 .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
 .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 255, 179)
 .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 12.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End With
```

change like that. i hope its help to you

Comment: I need certin rows to change according to certin conditions

Answer (score 0):

Complete Row:

```
datagrid1.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
```

Complete Column:

```
datagrid1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
```

With Condition and Particular cell

```
If (dataset1.Tables(0).Rows(1)(0) == "") Then
  datagrid1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample CustomClass:

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public string PropertyToBeWatched { get; set; }
    }
```

Created a list:

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "1"});
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });
            MyList.Add(new CustomClass() { PropertyToBeWatched = "2" });
```

Then created the Datagrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" RowStyle="{StaticResource Style1}">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PropertyToBeWatched}" Header="Property1"/>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Then the resources:

```
xmlns:sdk1="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" 
             xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"


 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Red" Color="#FFFF0000" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Green" Color="#FF00FF00" />    

        <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Test}}">
                            <sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="Root">
                                <sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                                    <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                                            <sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedEditing"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NormalEditing"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverUnfocusedEditing"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverEditing"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverUnfocusedSelected"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFF7D8DB" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                <sdk1:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                                <sdk1:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True"/>
                                <sdk1:DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                            </sdk1:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and this is for the converter:

```
public class RowStyleConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((CustomClass)value).PropertyToBeWatched == "1")
                return App.Current.Resources["Red"] as SolidColorBrush;
            else
                return App.Current.Resources["Green"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

It basically gets and sets the solidcolorbrush based on the property "PropertyToBeWatched".

Hope this helps